# LINQ pass in value for each iteration

Tags: linq

I have a list(mainlist) with the following

PsID  Nominprsn

---

1     James
2     Troy
3     Fred

There is a stored proc where I pass in the value of  PSID and Nominprsn and returns a result.

```
    var spresult = sp_getval(PSID, Nominprsn);
```

I am not sure how to go through the list and for each list pass in values value to the stored proc for that given record.

The output would be

PsID  Nominprsn  spresult

---

1     James      3
2     Troy       4
3     Fred       2

I know I can do something like

```
    var listv = (from ml in mainlist
                 select ml).ToList();
```

but not sure how to make the call to sp_getval for each iteration as I need to pass
the value of PsID and Nominprsn and pass it to sp_getval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking - but if I follow, you're saying that you want to map each entry in your list to the result of calling your sproc for that item in your list?

If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
var results = mainList.Select(item => sp_getval(item.PSID, item.Nominprsn))
```

edit: I just reread your question and see your desired output, in that case I'd do this:

```
var results = mainList.Select(item => new { 
                                            spResult: sp_getval(item.PSID, item.Nominprsn),
                                            PSID: item.PSID,
                                            Nominprsn: item.Nominprsn
                                           });
```

This will map each entry in your list to a new anonymous type with three members: the original two fields from your list objects, and a new spResult field containing the result of the SP call.

Comment: -I have a further question - spResult is a list and from that list, I need to get the 2nd row. Further, I need to get the column called PSDate. The value of PS is the spResult. Any idea on how I can do this

Comment: You could nest more LINQ inside on the sp_getval(args) call, but that gets messy fast - depending on what exactly is happening, i might either change the sproc (or create a new one) that returns what you need, or wrap the sproc call in another function that extracts just what you need from its result, and then call that newly created function in the LINQ above, passing the "item" to it (so spResult: myNewFunc(item), where myNewFunc take a list item, calls the sproc, and does any manipulation on the results thats needed)